# Unfolding Cube in SceneKit

Tags: swift, unity-game-engine, scenekit, maya

I am trying to make a simple app which shows a cube unfold into a 6-faces-plane, with the faces opening both inwards and outwards. Here's a [video](https://youtu.be/j3bMWu-F_NI).

Can this be done in SceneKit framework as I’ve been told it can’t be done but it has to be done in 3D software, exported as a `fbx` file and then imported into Unity. I’m not an app developer so just want to be sure. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried making your cube out of quads (GameObject -> 3d -> Object -> Quad),

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making your cube out of quads (GameObject -> 3d -> Object -> Quad). Then you can parent each of the quads to an empty gameObject positioned to where you want the cube face to pivot. Then make all  o f those gameObjects a child to a "Cube" parent. Then you can simply use Unity's built in animator to rotate each face around its pivot.

Answer (score 0):

If the question boils down to *"Is it true that this cannot be achieved with code alone, and a 3D tool must be used?"* then the answer is no.

This effect can be done programmatically without any 3D asset.

Answer (score 0):

You can unfold, or disassemble, a polygonal Cube not only inside Autodesk Maya (and then export it as `fbx` or `usdz`) but you can also do it using 6 square planes in SceneKit or in Unity. It's important to say that you need to position a `pivot point` of every square plane on its edge (by default `pivot point` is centered). Then you need to animate a 90 degrees rotation for every plane.

[image]

Here's a Swift code on how you can do it using SceneKit module:

```
import SceneKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet var sceneView: SCNView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        
        let scene = SCNScene()
        sceneView.scene = scene
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
        sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        
        // FIRST SIDE OF CUBE
        let planeNode_01 = SCNNode()
        planeNode_01.geometry = SCNPlane(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        planeNode_01.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
        planeNode_01.geometry?.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = .lambert
        planeNode_01.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
        planeNode_01.position.z = -0.5

        planeNode_01.simdPivot.columns.3.y = -0.5      // shifts pivot point
        planeNode_01.eulerAngles.x = CGFloat.pi / 4    // in radians
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode_01)
        
        // SECOND SIDE OF CUBE
        let planeNode_02 = SCNNode()
        planeNode_02.geometry = SCNPlane(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        planeNode_02.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
        planeNode_02.geometry?.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = .lambert
        planeNode_02.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green

        planeNode_01.simdPivot.columns.3.y = -0.5       // shifts pivot point
        planeNode_02.eulerAngles.x = CGFloat.pi / 2     // in radians
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode_02)

        // THIRD SIDE OF CUBE
        // ...
    }
}
```

[image]